# how to Spy on a serial port communication using c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I have 2 devices communicating throw a serial port, i ordered a "T" shaped serial port cable and can listen to the transaction between my 2 devices, when i try with a monitoring soft i have no problem to get ALL the data but when i try whith c# code i only get 1st line right and then i miss char and get "?" instead of some data. Here is more or less what i had on serialport datarecievedhandler:

```
private void DataReceviedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs 
e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;        
        this.Data = sp.ReadExisting();
    }
```

giving me line like : CRC ???ogram?? DA?E

I found topic where they talked about Multithreading to be able to continuously listen to port whithout having to stop to listen when "getting" data but this notion is new to me and i don't know how to inplement it.

Isn't there a way to recieve data until a timeout on a "Nodatasend" to then get my data and re-listen to my port ?

Comment: You see a ? when the SerialPort.Encoding could not translate the received byte.  The default is ASCIIEncoding so there are lots of possible byte values that produce ?.  Do favor Read() for a monitor style app so you don't depend on encoding.  And you see ? when the port could not receive the byte correctly, be sure to add a handler for the ErrorReceived event so you can see that happening.  Could be as simple as not setting the Parity, Stopbits or Databits properties correctly.

Comment: ok i see what u meant but when i tried with a free software monitoring i had to set Baudrate, stopbits parity and databits and got all data perfectly as i get "?" and MISSING charachter with my code with same "serialport-setting"

Comment: however i'll try to change settings to see if it solves the problem thx